# Open QGIS Project in both Linux/Windows

Tags: qgis-3, layers, windows, linux, file-path

My company has workers that use Windows and Linux to manage a QGIS project. However, when we use the same project created in different operate systems the layers lose file paths.

Is there possibility to create a compatible project created in Linux or Windows without the necessity to reset layers' file path?

Example below:
[image]

But in Linux the path of first one layer Americasul_x... is `/mnt/mairi/GEO_DADOS/3_VETOR/3.1_SHP/BASES_GERAIS_SHP/Americasul_xxxx_xx.shp` and it is different of how Windows system set it.

Answer (score 1):

I have all my data on an external drive, and the project file close to the data. I had the same problem with Windows 7 and Ubuntu, but think I have the answer.

In the Windows project I had "layer-tree-layer source="D:\Documents\GEOSCIENCE\WestTanami..." and in the Ubuntu project "layer-tree-layer source="./TopoMaps/E...".

So one is absolute paths and the other relative. I changed the Project-->Properties--> General in Windows to relative and it all started to look like the Ubuntu project - "layer-tree-layer source="./TopoMaps/Ex...".

The project now opens just the same in Windows and Ubuntu. Please let me know if this fix is good for you.