# Using QGIS projects in a multi-OS environment

Tags: qgis, windows, linux, file-path

I am using QGIS on a variety of systems all of which access various file systems in my network, one of which contains my files, another contains my QGIS projects. Unfortunately, depending on the OS, these are not always mounted in the same manner/directory.

The problem I have encountered is that if the project is saved on a system where data is in A:// and the QGIS project in B://, and if that same project is opened on for example a Unix system where data is mounted in /mnt/data and qgis is mounted in /mnt/documents those file links in the QGIS project will break. If they are saved as absolute paths, those are not correct anymore, and if they are saved as relative paths the location of the files relative to the project will have changed.

Two simple solutions to this problem would be either 1) to store the files and projects on the same drive as in [this GIS.SE question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341754/open-qgis-project-in-both-linux-windows) or 2) use different projects for each system. I would prefer not having to resort to 1) as there are other reasons why the files and projects are separated. 2) is also not particularly practical given that this is also a multi-user environment and it would add complications.

Has anyone encountered a similar situation and how did you solve it? Are there any QGIS plugins that might help in this situation? I had a quick search through the plugin manager but could not find anything obvious.

Is it possible to have some sort of OS-dependent variable that defines where drives are mounted? - eg. if Ubunutu data-head=/mnt/data else data-head=A://

Comment: We use a windows share drive and access through QGIS on Windows and Linux Mint, without issue... If you get using postgresql, you can store QGIS projects in there as well.

Comment: Thanks for the hint I did not know that, we do actually use PostGIS a lot so this will be really useful. The issue here is that we use several share drives so we cannot use relative paths - which would otherwise work across different OS on one drive.